# find() does not get the existing row

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a resource Controller with this `index` method like this:

```
public function index()
{
        $args = [];
        $args = array_merge($args, $this->data_creator(35, 12, 'book'));
        $args = array_merge($args, $this->data_creator(37, 12, 'kit'));
        $args = array_merge($args, $this->data_creator(38, 12, 'game'));

        $args['menu_links'] = [
            'books'     => route('shopping-products.category', Category::find(25)->slug),
            'videos'    => route('shopping-products.category', Category::find(24)->slug),
            'kits'      => route('shopping-products.category', Category::find(23)->slug),
            'games'     => route('shopping-products.category', Category::find(22)->slug),
        ];
    
        return view('frontend.shop.products.index', $args);
}
```

But it returns this error:

**Trying to get property 'slug' of non-object**

And when I `dd(Category::find(25), Category::find(24), Category::find(23), Category::find(22));` I get *NULL* results.

Meaning that it can not find data with specified ids.

However there are 25 records stored at the `categories` table:

[image]

So what is going wrong here?

**UPDATE #1**:

`Category.php` Model:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use Sluggable, SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cat_id';
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'cat_name'
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function path()
    {
        return "/products/categories/$this->slug";
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'cat_parent_id', 'cat_id');
    }

    public function parents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'cat_id', 'cat_parent_id');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'category_products', 'ctp_cat_id', 'ctp_prd_id');
    }

    public function news()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(News::class, 'category_news', 'ctn_cat_id', 'ctn_nws_id');
    }

    public function galleries()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Gallery::class, 'category_galleries', 'ctg_cat_id', 'ctg_gly_id');
    }

    public function uploaded()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UploadedFile::class, 'upf_object_id', 'cat_id')->where('upf_object_type_id', '=', '107');
    }

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class, 'article_category', 'act_cat_id', 'act_art_id');
    }

    public function olympiadExam()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(OlympiadExam::class, 'olympiads_exams_categories', 'oec_ole_id', 'oec_cat_id');
    }

    public function olympiadExamQuestion()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(OlympiadExamQuestion::class, 'olympiads_exams_questions_categories', 'oes_cat_id', 'oes_oeq_id')->orderBy('oeq_number', 'asc');
    }

    public function attr_attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CategoryAttribute::class, 'category_id', 'cat_id');
    } //

    public function attr_product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'prd_cat_att_id', 'cat_id');
    } //

    public function couponRelation()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(couponRelation::class, 'object_id', 'cat_id')->where('object_type', 'product_category');
    }

    public function magazines()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Magazine::class, 'category_magazine', 'category_id', 'magazine_id');
    }

}
```

**UPDATE #2**:

Result of `dd(Category::where('cat_id', 25), Category::where('cat_id', 24), Category::where('cat_id', 23), Category::where('cat_id', 22));`:

[image]

**UPDATE #3**:

Result of `dd(Category::where('cat_id', 25)->get(), Category::where('cat_id', 24)->get(), Category::where('cat_id', 23)->get(), Category::where('cat_id', 22)->get());`

[image]

Comment: Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68174694/edit) your `Category` model code to the question? I guess, `cat_id` is not configured as the model's primary key.

Comment: @shaedrich I just added it as **UPDATE #1**,

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are you using Laravel 8, or Laravel 5.8? That's a huge difference

Comment: @NicoHaase I have defined `cat_id` as primary key and there are 25 records existing at the table, but `dd(Category::find(25), Category::find(24), Category::find(23), Category::find(22));` returns *NULL* !

Comment: What happens if you do `dd(Category::where('cat_id', 25), Category:::where('cat_id', 24), Category:::where('cat_id', 23), Category:::where('cat_id', 22));`?

Comment: @shaedrich I just added **UPDATE #2**,

Comment: Oh, sorry: `dd(Category::where('cat_id', 25)->get(), Category:::where('cat_id', 24)->get(), Category:::where('cat_id', 23)->get(), Category:::where('cat_id', 22)->get());`

Comment: @shaedrich Plz checkout **UPDATE #3**

Comment: Please adjust the tagging of your question: are you using Laravel 8, or 5.8? Also, what have you tried to resolve the problem? Why not start a debugger to check where this goes wrong?

Comment: I'm almost at my wit's end. It almost seems like the database, Laravel is trying to access is not the same as you're showing us.

Comment: @NicoHaase This is Laravel 5.8 project but the logic is the same. Can u please tell me how to debug this?

Comment: Using XDebug, this might be the easiest way. Set a breakpoint on `Category::where()` in your controller, and step through until you reach the SQL query that is generated

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [`barryvdh/laravel-debugbar`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)

Comment: Provide migration up() code. If you change anything in id, then provide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `SoftDeletes` trait then laravel just update `deleted_at` column. The column isn't actually deleted from database, it just marked as delete.
To find columns which is softly deleted, use `Model::withTrashed()->find()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes @Bapi is right, might be deleted_at column of table **categories** is not null, and that's why your model is not returning it, Either nullify the deleted_at column or accessed Model::withTrashed()->find();